# How to install tshark on Docker?

Tags: docker, installation, dockerfile, tshark, docker-for-mac

I want to install tshark on ubuntu17.04 on Docker for Mac with Dockerfile. 
I am using docker-compose

In `apt install tshark`, there is a following prompt.
The prompt stopping install despite I typed `yes`.

How to install tshark in Dockerfile?

```
Dumpcap can be installed in a way that allows members of the "wireshark" system
group to capture packets. This is recommended over the alternative of running
Wireshark/Tshark directly as root, because less of the code will run with
elevated privileges.

For more detailed information please see
/usr/share/doc/wireshark-common/README.Debian.

Enabling this feature may be a security risk, so it is disabled by default. If
in doubt, it is suggested to leave it disabled.

Should non-superusers be able to capture packets? [yes/no] yes
```

Answer (score 13):

```
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y tshark
```

Will install without needing user interaction.

Comment: Have no idea why, but if I had tshark at the end of package list to install it does not work. If I had it as single one, works perfectly:
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update && apt-get install -y tshark
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git python python-pip iputils-ping traceroute

Comment: @Tomasz I'm having exactly the same issue, did you find the reason why is it behaving in this way?

Answer (score 1):

First, you generally have (to avoid having to type 'yes'):

```
RUN apt install -yq xxx
```

Second:

- you can check out this [tshark image](https://hub.docker.com/r/opennsm/tshark/~/dockerfile/), which does install dumcap; by compiling wireshark, which produced dumpcap.
- the alternative (no compilation, only install) is [this image](https://hub.docker.com/r/wearelifetrading/adrian_ubuntu/~/dockerfile/)

The install command becomes in that last case:

```
# Install build wireshark, need to run as root RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wireshark && \
    groupadd wireshark && \
    usermod -aG wireshark developer && \
    setcap 'CAP_NET_RAW+eip CAP_NET_ADMIN+eip' /usr/bin/dumpcap && \
    chgrp wireshark /usr/bin/dumpcap && \
    chmod 750 /usr/bin/dumpcap
```

Comment: I tried First example `RUN apt install -yq tshark`
But the prompt make stopping installation.

Comment: @KiYugadgeter OK. Maybe the second example would be better in that case. Regarding the first example, make sure ti use the same base image.

Comment: I have also attempted second way.
but same message displaying.

Answer (score 0):

I just made it

```
docker exec -it <container ID> /bin/sh
apt update
apt-get install tshark
```

-i,

--interactive          Keep STDIN open even if not attached

--privileged           Give extended privileges to the command

-t, --tty                  Allocate a pseudo-TTY